# apache2.4, php-fpm, proxypassmatch "No protocol handler was valid for the URL.."

Tags: php, apache

I'm stuck trying to get an apache2.4 vhost to pass php requests to php5-fpm.

I've configured php5-fpm to listen on a socket, with this line in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

The only vhost I have configured on this particular machine is the default host. This is how I've configured it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default-access.log combined


        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:///var/run/php5-
        fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www/html/

        DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php


</VirtualHost>
```

After configuration, I've restarted apache. Requests for a test php file yield this message in the error log.

> [client 10.0.2.2:51434] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the
>   URL /info.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure
>   the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using
>   LoadModule.

I'm reasonably sure that I have the right modules installed. 'apachectl -M' returns the following:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fastcgi_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug in Debian. It works with `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/"` but doesn't work with `"sock:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock"`. In your case php5-fpm.sock. Be careful about the port number 9000 when switching from the socket.

So the Answer is: change php-fpm to listen on ip:port

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

And voilà!

Notes: Try `LogLevel debug` in your VirtualHost definition. This is what I see:

```
AH01076: url: unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock/var/www/test.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
AH01077: declining URL unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock/var/www/test.php
```